# If you add the same string to two different lists or collections in Python, are you using twice the memory?

Tags: python

For instance if you add the same string to a dict and a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A copy of the string is not put into both, they just both point to the one string.

Comment: And strings in Pyhton are immutable, so you will never see an odd effect like modifying a string in one container mysteriously affecting a string in another.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable and are never copied. Indeed, even if you manually request a copy, you'll still get the same object:

```
>>> import copy
>>> s = "abc"
>>> t = copy.copy(s)
>>> u = copy.deepcopy(s)
>>> id(s), id(t), id(u)
(139730866789424, 139730866789424, 139730866789424)
>>> s is t, s is u
(True, True)
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's the *same* string, only one copy of it exists (and two references to that single object).  Two strings that are equal on the other hand can very well end up as two copies, depending on what optimizations the compiler is able to do to avoid the duplication.

Consider, for example (Python 2.6 or earlier -- not sure what further optimizations may be added in the future):

```
>>> def f1(s, d, l):
...   d['z'] = s
...   l.append(s)
... 
>>> d={}
>>> l=[]
>>> f1('ciao', d, l)
>>> d['z'] is l[0]
True
>>> def f1(s, d, l):
...   d['z'] = s + 'zap'
...   l.append(s + 'zap')
... 
>>> f1('ciao', d, l)
>>> d['z'] is l[1]
False
>>> d['z'] == l[1]
True
>>>
```

The first one's a no-brainer -- clearly the same object.  The second one involves two equal strings -- if the compiler was smarter it *could* have detected the equality and optimized things to avoid the duplication, but, in general, Python's compiler is tuned to compile very fast, not to spend much time optimizing things.

Comment: Of course, if you use `intern` you can get a single global copy of a given string.  I used this to greatly reduce memory usage in a Python program I wrote to analyze datasets in the 10s of millions of records in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you have a single string object:

```
s = "Some string."
```

And you add it to, say, a dict and a list:

```
d = {"akey": s}
l = [s]
```

Then `d["akey"]` and `l[0]` will point to the same string object as `s`, not two different objects with the content "Some string.".